# TrackballControls change events

Tags: three.js

I have a static scene with no animation loop, and am trying to use the change event of TrackballControls to trigger the render function following the pattern in this [thread](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/5757#issuecomment-66896561), i.e.:

```
var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

This works well with OrbitControls, but the change events don't fire when I substitute TrackballControls.  However, if I add the line:

```
_this.update();
```

at the end of mousewheel(), mousemove(), and touchmove() functions in TrackballControls.js, I can get the change events to fire correctly (in my case, anyway). I am not sure if this is the best way to get the change events firing.  Is forking a local copy of TrackballControls the best solution for this case, have I overlooked something, or does it make sense to change TrackballControls.js?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TrackballControls` was written to require an animation loop in which `controls.update()` is called.

`OrbitControls`, on the other hand, can be used in static scenes in which the scene is rendered only when the mouse is moved, like so:

```
controls.addEventListener( 'change', render );
```

In either case, the controls are part of the examples -- not the library -- so you are free to hack them to your liking.

What you are proposing is fine if your scene is static and there is no damping required.

EDIT: corrected for three.js r.73

Comment: That explains it.  After playing with the two controls a bit more, I do like the damping effect.  I may end up writing some code that runs an animation loop until the camera motion damps to a stop, so I can get the effect and still not have the overhead of a constantly running animation loop.

Comment: Is there a cleaner way of running TrackballControls without a render loop, and without having to modify the TrackballControls.js file? I tried using tb.addEventListener('mousemove',tb.update) but it doesn't work...

Comment: I am getting TrackballControls from three-trackballcontrols on npm, so hacking it is inconvenient.